# MVP in asp.net, where to program filling the UI with data from existing data?

Tags: asp.net, mvp, webformsmvp

i'm at a new client where they implemented the mvp pattern.

now i want to use it to, but what i can't find in their code is this:
i open a asp form with an id in the querystring. i get the dataobject with that id, and now i've got an object which i want to show in the textboxes in the asp.net form.

i have this:

i created a presenter

the presenter has a constructor which takes a IxxxView

the aspx page implements the IxxxView

in the aspx i have a reference to the presenter

in the load of the aspx, i instantiate the presenter with (this)

i pass the id of the object to the presenter, the presenter gets the data...

(so far so good?)

and then, i have an object in the presenter, and textboxes in the view.

what should i do know?

Comment: If presenter methods return void you should take desired result from presenter's public property and populate view's object by them.

Comment: can you be a little more clear to me?

Comment: Ok, show please signature of presenter's method.

Comment: i don't have a signature of a method yet, i only have what i descibed above, and i'm looking for the way to do this

Comment: There's good MVP-framework - http://webformsmvp.com/. You can use it for creating WebForms MVP-application or use it for learning.

Answer (score 0):

In a fairly typical MVP implementation, I would expect that the IView interface will specify events. The Presenter, when it gets the reference to the IView (in your case, that would be in the presenter's constructor), should attach event handlers for any event it wants to handle. Very often, one of the events will be to signal the presenter that the data should be put into the view, or put into a view model for the view to bind to. Sometimes, the event will signal that the presenter should take some kind of action, like updating the model, or starting a process.

In WebFormsMvp, after your presenter has loaded the data into the view's viewmodel (by setting the View.Model property), the view can bind to the viewmodel by use of binding syntax. For example, your textbox control might look something like this:

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" DataSource="<%# Model.Data %>" />
```

If you are not using WebFormsMvp, then you just want to make sure the Presenter has a way to pass the data into the view. You could do this by adding a property to the IView that the user control implements. When the setter for the property is called, it will need to pass the value into the appropriate control. Likewise, when the getter for that property is called, it should return the value of that control.

For example, your user control could include a property implementation like this:

```
string IMyView.ViewData
{
    get { return TextBox1.Text; }
    set { TextBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

However, if you want to get fancy, you could work with DataSource controls, as well. The main thing to remember is that if you are adopting MVP, you want to keep the View part as simple as possible, because views are more difficult to test than presenters. So the View should do as little as possible -- set values, get values, and fire events, and very little else. Dynamic View behavior like hiding or showing elements, highlighting or not highlighting, etc., should be controlled by the Presenter using either properties of the IView interface, or through the ViewModel that the Presenter and View share.

Personally, I prefer and recommend using WebFormsMvp.